# Hashing then store the token, how much cost does it take?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, security, hash, cryptography

I am trying to create something safe, but not terrible.

What I need is to find a user in my database and then edits fields in that user. 
The way I currently do this is with code like this:

```
exports.buyItem = function(req, res, next) {
var token = req.body.token;
var playerID = req.body.playerID;
User.findOne({ token: SHA256(token)+playerID },
///implementation ( do something for that user)
```

Explanation: 
When the user logs in, a randomly generated token is created.
The token is then sent back to the user.
And it is also hashed and stored in the database (concatenated with the playerID)

**Now each time my user makes a request to the database he sends the token + playerID to the server which then validates as in the code above. (It checks if the hashed token +playerID is in the database)**

Now, my questions are:

- Given that the server would have a lot of traffic, would calculating
  the hash every time a user requests something be a problem?(Would the SHA256 calculations destroy the server?)
- Do you see any other problem with the implementation, and do you have a suggestion as to what I should do differently?

I would prefer not using cookies.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem if your website is not as hot as StackOverflow. hashing is fast. BTW, you'd better hash the playerID into the token. i.e. `token: SHA256(token+playerID)`.

Comment: I have done this in the generation of the token itself to begin with.`var token = function() {
  return rand() +"."+ playerID +"."+ rand();
 };`

Comment: Your question title is completely misleading, this question is about security and as such is off-topic. FWIW, your current approach is really not giving you any security at all. Try [security.stackexchange.com](http://security.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be better to use a asynchronous hashing API ( APIs which let you to give a callback ), crypto in nodejs provide this. If you use a sync ( blocking ) API, your nodejs will not be able to do anything else during hashing.

And for reference, 10^7 sha256s takes 38667ms in my computer ( using **sync** API ). ( 3µs per hash, or 259khash/s )

> What if I made the user hash the token on his machine and then upload it along with his playerID? That way the server only has to do the lookup for the user.

If you do that, hashing won't provide secretly at all.

I guess the reason you want to hash is to protect user from hackers when your database is leaked. Hacker that get the stored token won't be able to use that because he needs to find the original token. But if you hash it client-side, hacker can still use that token because he just need to submit it to the server without needing to know what the original token is.

Comment: What if I made the user hash the token on his machine and then upload it along with his playerID? That way the server only has to do the lookup for the user.

Comment: @RasmusLauridsen explained.

Comment: Ah yeah, I got it! And yes, protecting users from leak is exactly what I want! 
The first thing you said does that mean that: if 250k users made a request at the same time, it would take 1 second to handle? I think I am using crypto in node.js but the way I do it now, is it blocking?

Comment: @RasmusLauridsen 

> if 250k users made a request at the same time, it would take 1 second to handle?

Yes for only hashing. your nodejs will probably crash if you are running it on a server that has the same speed as my computer and you are facing 250kuser/s.

> I think I am using crypto in node.js but the way I do it now, is it blocking?

You means you are using sync API? It is blocking. When you are hashing, nothing (on nodejs) will run at once. So you should use async API.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
I will now see if I can figure out how to make it async :)

Comment: @RasmusLauridsen If you give me a upvote, I will thanks you a lot :) I still need some reps. to edit comm. wiki

Comment: I tried to do that, but unfortunately I don't have enough rep to do it (this is my first post)

Comment: @RasmusLauridsen So there you go!

Answer (score 0):

Imho calculating hash on every request is quite costly.
I'll try to explain my approach for authorization:

Every time user is created, he/she is assigned with really hard token (that is indexing by string in mongodb or *sql databases)
https://github.com/vodolaz095/hunt/blob/master/lib/misc/rack.js#L19.
Also this random strings has random salt to make them more hard.

This token than is saved as key to user's session. Passport.js framework was used to find users via this key
https://github.com/vodolaz095/hunt/blob/master/lib/http/passport.js#L13

Every time user access site, he/she gives this token, and backend extract user from database using this token.
It worked for me for 400-500  active users on one 512 RAM vps.
Main advantage for me was security - there was a feature to regenerate this token for user, which results in immediate logging if from all sessions this user created.

For your approach, i think generating the token on each request is quite over powered, we can issue secured and tampering protected sessions via [Express Session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) like this https://github.com/vodolaz095/hunt/blob/master/lib/http/expressApp.js#L218-L226.

And pass unique user key (not id) as query/body parameter to find user.

Note the `secret`, `httpOnly` tags - first makes session cookies values to be more more district, the second one makes sessions only accessible by browser, not by client side javascript

Comment: Sorry, but these things you have said is quite hard to understand.. (barely been programming for a year in total) what if I made the user hash the token on his machine and then upload it along with his playerID? That way the server only has to do the lookup for the user.

Answer (score 0):

Encryption and hashing is computationally intensive, but if you want security there is no way around it. For example, if you are using SSL, then your server is encrypting and decrypting EVERYTHING it sends and receives anyway.

I've found that a much bigger bottleneck is accessing a disk database on each request, which can add 100-200ms easy. So I use Redis as a token store. By comparison a hash is maybe a couple ms.

I was creating a solution that accepts a variety of authentication providers, and generates a random token along with a password to each user. I store the token in Redis, along with a salt and hash of the password.

I used Passport's http bearer strategy to authenticate each endpoint without cookies. The user sends a header:
`Authorization: Bearer token:password`

I then check Redis for the token and if it is not found, the request is terminated. Next, I hash the password and salt to verify it. The user is authenticated in a matter of milliseconds. I chose the pbkdf2, but SHA256 is faster if performance is critical.

Here is an [article](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16354/whats-the-advantage-of-using-pbkdf2-vs-sha256-to-generate-an-aes-encryption-key) comparing the pros and cons of each.

If you aren't storing sensitive data, and performance is more important than security then you could store your session tokens un-hashed. The advantage of hashing is that even if somebody hacks into your database, they can't use the data they steel to gain access to user accounts.

But definitely using a memory store for tokens (e.g. Redis) will give you much better performance than MongoDB.

My project [SuperLogin](https://github.com/colinskow/superlogin) is built for a CouchDB backend, but you are welcome to browse the source code and reverse engineer it. It would be simple to convert it for MongoDB use.

Comment: PBKDF2 is chosen _because_ it is slow. If an attacker gains access to your hashed you need to slow them down as much as possible. The reason is that users may have reused the password on your site somewhere else more sensitive. SHA-256 is fine though for hashing 128 bit tokens generated from a CSPRNG.